# Как написать программу на java , которая будет разбивать строку на равные подстроки указанной длины?

Tags: java

Гарантируется, что длина подстроки кратна кол-ву подстрок

Comment: Может быть, стоит посмотреть, какие методы есть у string?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){subs[i] = str.substring(i * sLength, (i + 1) * sLength);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам вопрос очень абстрактный
Но вот как то так...

```
    @Test
    void sss() {
        breakSubstring("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmwfffzxcfffq", 4);
    }

    void breakSubstring(String myString, int length) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (myString.length() > length) {
            String get = myString.substring(0, length);
            myString = myString.replaceFirst(get, "");

            list.add(get);
        }
        list.add(myString);

        System.out.println("result = " + list);
    }
```

Вывод:

> result = [qwer, tyui, opas, dfgh, jklz, xcvb, nmwf, ffzx, cfff, q]

Comment: Вы тут каждую итерацию создаете 2 строки. Это будет работать, но несколько неэффективно с точки зрения памяти и скорости, особенно если на входе будет большая строка.

Answer (score 1):

Вот с **массивом** `String`:

```
public class mine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (String sd : substring("String", 2)) {
            System.out.println("s = " + sd); 
        }
    }

    public static String[] substring(String str, int countSubStr) {
        int strLength = str.length() / countSubStr;
        String[] result = new String[countSubStr];
        for (int j = 0; j < countSubStr; j++)
            result[j] = str.substring(strLength * j, strLength * (j + 1);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> s = Str
>   s = ing